# How to parse data from this api and display it in my html?

Tags: javascript, html, json, api

I am brand new to javascript and have spent the past few hours trying to parse json data from an api url into my body in my html document. My only experience with APIs are with C# wrappers so this is new to me.

This is the API url: https://catfact.ninja/fact

I'm not sure where to go from here. I've been able to successfully pull the data I want, but I'm only able to print it to the console and I'm not sure how to pull that data into html. Here is my javascript code:

```
var HttpClient = function() {
this.get = function(aUrl, aCallback) {
    var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
    var anHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    anHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (anHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && anHttpRequest.status == 200)
            aCallback(anHttpRequest.responseText);
    }

    anHttpRequest.open( "GET", aUrl, true );
    anHttpRequest.send( null );
    }
}
var client = new HttpClient();
client.get('https://catfact.ninja/fact', function(response) {
    var vsplit = response.split("\"")
    console.log(vsplit[3]);
    $('body').html(document.write(vsplit[3]));

});
```

Thanks for any help, sorry if I seem dumb

Comment: check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML looks like you want to select the elements innerHTML and set it to your data. You might need to turn it into a string first with ```JSON.stringify(thing, null, 2)``` where "thing" is your data, null is not important =) and 2 is the spacing for json formatting. You might also try and extract the object's value you're after explicitly.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm super lost! I don't mean for you to write my code for me but do you think you can walk me through it perhaps?

Comment: sure. write it up on codepen or the like and i'll take a look at it

Comment: also, try using axios instead of xmlhttp request. it will pull your data in a format much easier to deal with. then you won't have to do any re-formatting

Comment: https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios

Answer (score 0):

The first issue you have is that the call to document.write in the html function will not produce the results you think. document.write is a synchronous write function that tries to inject a string into the DOM renderer at the point it's called. If you remove that, you should have more luck seeing something in the HTML, but you can also use the following.

The response from https://catfact.ninja/fact is the following.

```
{"fact":"Cats' eyes shine in the dark because of the tapetum, a reflective layer in the eye, which acts like a mirror.","length":109}
```

There's no need to split the response when the format is JSON. You can use JSON.parse to create a Javascript Object. For example.

```
// data will contain data.fact, and data.length 
var data = JSON.parse(response);

// Without using jQuery, you can set the html of the body directly
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.innerHTML = data.fact;
```

Comment: I just tried that out but I'm still getting nothing appearing when I load my html file

Comment: Can you paste any responses from the console? Also, when are you calling the client.get function? Are you waiting for the document to load? You should be waiting for the body onload event, or the jQuery document ready event.